# Conceptual question about equivalent relations and bijections?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. What is the correlation between equivalence relation and bijection?
2. Is equivalence relation a synonym for bijection?
3. Does equivalence relation always imply there exist a bijection?

[image]

I was reading Definition 2.3 and 2.4. I got out of it that equivalent relations are somehow related to bijections.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the excerpt you've cited demonstrates poor pedagogy by introducing a concept as important as equivalence relations in such a comment.

What the excerpt is saying is that the "relation" on the "set of all sets" (**warning**: there is no such thing, that is why I am using scare quotes) defined by
$$A\sim B\iff\text{ there exists a bijection }f:A\to B$$
is an equivalence relation. While it is important to observe this property, it is by no means the only thing there is to say about bijections, nor is it the only example of an equivalence relation.

---

Equivalence relations are not related to bijections.

Given a set $X$, a **relation** on $X$ is a subset $R$ of the set $X^2=\{(x,y):x,y\in X\}$. We say that $R$ is an **equivalence relation** if it has these properties:

1. $(x,x)\in R$ for all $x\in X$.
2. $(x,y)\in R$ $\implies$ $(y,x)\in R$
3. $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$ $\implies$ $(x,z)\in R$

Given sets $X$ and $Y$, a **bijection** from $X$ to $Y$ is a function $f:X\to Y$ with the property that for all $y\in Y$, there exists exactly one $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Equivalently, $f:X\to Y$ is a bijection if there exists a function $g:Y\to X$ such that $(g\circ f)=\mathrm{id}_X$ and $(f\circ g)=\mathrm{id}_Y$.

*(If one interprets a function $f:X\to Y$ as a subset of $X\times Y$, then technically one can compare equivalence relations on a set $X$ with functions $X\to X$; the only function that is an equivalence relation, and the only equivalence relation that is a function, is the identity function $\mathrm{id}_X:X\to X$.)*

It sounds like what you're thinking of are ***partitions*** and equivalence relations, which are equivalent mathematical notions, as described by the *"fundamental theorem of equivalence relations"* ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Fundamental_theorem_of_equivalence_relations)).

Comment: For definition 2.4 (c), is that an equivalent relation or a bijection or both?

Comment: @user122965: The book has defined the notation
$$X\sim Y$$
(where $X$ and $Y$ are sets) to ***mean***
$$\text{there exists a bijection from }X\text{ to }Y$$
So while the notation $\sim$ is not literally itself a bijection in that excerpt, it is saying there exists one.

Comment: Okay that makes much more sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

What these definitions say is that one particular equivalence relation on the class of sets can be defined by the means of bijections: in a precise way, sets $A$ and $B$ are *equivalent* is there exists a bijection from $A$to $B$.

But a general equivalence relation is a relation that satisfies the three properties that @Zev Cholones recalled. And indeed the equivalence between sets defined with bijections (it is also called *equipotence*) satisfies them all:

1. $A\sim A$, because $\operatorname{id}_A$ is trivially a bijection.
2. If $A\sim B$, i.e. if there exists a bijection $f\colon  A\to B$, then $B\sim A$, i.e. there exists a bijection $g\colon B\to A$: it is enough to take the reciprocal of $f$, which is also a bijection.
3. If $A\sim B$ and $B\sim C$, then $A\sim C$: Indeed if $f\colon A\to B$  and $g\colon B\to C$  are bijections, then $g\circ f\colon A\to C$ is a bijection.

Comment: A minor comment about phrasing that nevertheless may be important for clarifying for the OP: in your first sentence, you wrote "equivalence relation between sets $A$ and $B$", but (to me) that makes it sound like "equivalence relation" is a kind of function from $A$ to $B$, or instead like the "equivalence relation" is **on** either $A$ or $B$. I feel it's important to point out that the (unstated) "location" of the equivalence relation described in the excerpt is the collection of all sets.

Comment: @Zev Cholones: Yes, you're right. I made  my answer more explicit. I hope it be without ambiguity (I used the term class purposely, because it has a precise meaning in axiomatic set theory, and also a general, intuitive meaning).